# 'GridView' does not contain definition for 'RowIndex' and no extension method 'RowIndex' accepting first argument of type 'xGridView' could be found

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, gridview, row

I am using MS Visual Studio 2010 and I imported this aspx which I believe was from an older version Framework.

```
protected void selectedbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string PKname = ""; int k = 0;
    foreach (GridView row in this.selectMedGridView.Rows)
    {

        CheckBox cbox = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("selrecord");
        if (cbox.Checked)
        {
            PKname += "ID=" + this.selectMedGridView.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value.ToString().Trim() + "&";
        }
        k++;
    }
    Response.Redirect("view_selected_med_records.aspx?" + PKname);

}
```

I received this Error and it seems to have something to do with the word `RowIndex`. I assume this syntax does not exist in the newer version.

However I have no idea what is the new syntax. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2):

The type of the iteration variable needs to be `GridViewRow` not `GridView`

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in this.selectMedGridView.Rows)
```

Comment: This is also a good case for using 'var' since it will just work.

Comment: Wow thanks. That solved the problem.
I have no idea the error is due to somewhere else

Comment: @DavidKhaykin don't think so. The `GridViewRowCollection` is a non-generic collection hence `var` would simply infer `object`